# Builds being kicked on committing to remote branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following build file

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - src/minted
    exclude:
      - README.md
schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: Daily midnight build
    branches:
      include:
      - main
```

This config is firing builds on commits on every branch. What I'm trying to do is only fire build when there is a PR submitted against main and building from the main branch on a schedule. What I'm I missing here ?

Comment: Where is this yaml file with your 'correct' configuration stored? Only on the main branch, or also in all existing branch? Azure pipelines will default to the main branch, but will try to honor the configuration of stored in each branch.

Comment: Are you using Azure Repos? Because the `pr` section is only for BitBucket and GitHub. Refer to the documentation for instructions on configuring a branch policy for Azure Repos.

Answer (score 1):

If no trigger is specified, then every change will trigger the pipeline.

Add following at the beginning of your yaml.

```
trigger: none
```